# How to deserialize WWW form field to enum in Spring?

Tags: spring-boot, kotlin, enums, spring-restcontroller

I'm facing issue when trying deserialize input coming from WWW form to enum class in Spring application, in Kotlin.

My DTO and enum classes:

```
enum class Status(@get:JsonValue val value: Int) {
    NORMAL(0),
    ERROR(1);

    companion object {
        @JvmStatic
        @JsonCreator
        fun of(number: Int?): Status? {
            return values().find { it.value == number }
        }
    }
}

data class RequestData(val status: Status?)
```

Controller's POST request receiver method:

```
@PostMapping("/post")
fun register(@Valid data: RequestData, error: Errors) {}
```

When I make POST request with `status = 0` using Postman, request's failing with following exception.

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Parameter specified as non-null is null: method com.example.Controller.post, parameter data
```

When I make request with `status = NORMAL` then no exception, but that what I don't want.
I'm using `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` content type in POST request.
Please let me know where I'm doing wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may use Converter class for that. Note that request parameters my look like a numbers to you, but they are in fact strings. That's why converter below accepts `String?` and returns `Status?`. That means, it would be convenient for you if your `enum` accept it as well. Example: `NORMAL("0"), ERROR("1")`.

```
class ConvStringToStatus : Converter<String?, Status?> {
    override fun convert(source: String?) = Status.of(source)
}
```

To make it work, converter must be registered as below.

```
@Configuration
class WebConfig : WebMvcConfigurer {
    override fun addFormatters(registry: FormatterRegistry) {
        registry.addConverter(ConvStringToStatus())
    }
}
```

Comment: Why isn't Jackson conversion taking care of it, though? Why do we have to implement our own converter for that? I have a simlar issue when trying to use an enum as query param. And I'm using `'com.fasterxml.jackson.module:jackson-module-kotlin'`, which succeeds in converting my enum on its own, but Spring does not seem to use it...

Comment: Jackson works with JSON primarily. Above, it's not a JSON body, so Jackson doesn't apply.

Comment: Didn't realize that at first, but indeed query params don't go through JSON conversion, and have no reason to, because they are simply not JSON

Answer (score 0):

You just use the name.

ex) status = NORMAL

And does `value` matter? You can use ordinal

```
enum class Status{
    NORMAL,
    ERROR,
}

println(NORMAL.ordinal)
//result:0
```

This is a joke, but if you need

```
enum class Status(val value:String){
    `0`("NORMAL"),`1`("ERROR")
}

println(data.status.value)
```

Comment: You should avoid using ordinals. It is very easy to change the order (ex. move ERROR above NORMAL) and your application wouldn't work properly anymore. More of it, it'd be difficult for you to find out where the error is because, at the surface, everything would look nice, compilation would look OK, etc. When numbers are explicit, it is much more clear how to convert them and reorganizing your code wouldn't affect the result.

Comment: Thank you for your kind comments.

Comment: As a matter of fact I also prefer to avoid using the enum constant names, because these are merely variable names and should be changeable without breaking the API.

Answer (score 0):

For anyone still looking and finding this. The example code works and does not throw `non-null field is null` exception if you add `jackson-module-kotlin` dependency. It should match your `com.fasterxml.jackson.core` version

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.module</groupId>
    <artifactId>jackson-module-kotlin</artifactId>
    <version>2.9.8</version>
</dependency>
```